# laravel 5.5 Localization url

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel locale, need to show language sign at the URL, 
I created a route group like so, and listed my routes inside the group

```
Route::group(['prefix' =>  App::getLocale()], function(){
 Route::get('login','Hostato\Admin\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')
  ->name('login');
});
```

but it always show 'localhost:8000/en/logoin', although if i render at the view

```
{{ App::getLocale() }}
```

it shows the correct chosen language sign

at the route group prefix do i need to use another way rather than ?

```
App::getLocale()
```

Comment: It's likely that your locale is set after the routes are registered. Try moving the locale detection to a service provider which runs before that. However your solution will result in 404 pages if someone tries to visit them in the wrong locale (i.e. not the locale they've selected). What @alexey.mezenin suggested will work better with deep links.

Comment: Thank you for response , detection to a service provider  make since let me try that and let you know

Comment: @apokryfos nope it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You should use parameter instead of hardcoding the `setLocale()` method call:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{lang}'], function() {
```

And then in [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware) set locale:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    app()->setLocale($request->lang);
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: thank you for response, but this is how i had it first but then i have to pass the lang parameters at each link example 
{{ Route('login', Session::get('locale')) }},
so i thought of another way to put the language sign at the prefix 
i tried it this way at the routes 

Route::group(['prefix' =>Session::get('locale')], function(){...})
but it didn't work

Comment: @AdamIbrahim If you only ever have the session set locale working for each user why do you need a prefix?